# Store foreach in array and email

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

I'm having issues trying to take multiple results from a foreach loop, store them in an array and then email the finalised array. I've got something like this so far:

```
foreach ($term as $term) {
    $dbdata =   $term['term'];
    $user   =   $term['email'];
    $html = file_get_html('www.test.com/test');
    $partial = $html->find('ul.test');
    $host = 'www.test.com';
    $a = new \SimpleXMLElement($partial); //Grab just the relative url
    $href = $a['href'];
    $html2 = file_get_contents($host.$href);
    if (preg_match("/$dbdata/i", $html2)) {
        $data =  array(
            'term' => $dbdata,
            'link' => $link,
            'user' => $user,
            'from' => 'myproject@test.com'
        );

        Mail::queue( 'emails.sup', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
            $message->to( $data['user'] )
                ->from( $data['from'])
                ->subject( 'We got the following things for you!' );
        });
    }
}
```

This is using Laravel. I know this is a very simple thing but I'm having a total mind blank with it. Any advice welcome!

Thanks :)

Comment: Try foreach ($term as $term) { $val = $term; } and then use $val where needed

Comment: Hey, gave that a go but it only shows one term rather than both :/

Comment: I would need to see more code to really help you